# Spring not injecting singleton bean controller into another controller

Tags: spring, javafx, javabeans, code-injection

I'm writing an app that uses spring for dependency injection and javafx for the gui. in the spring config i defined all my beans (DAOs, Services and GUI controllers). sofar everything has worked great. however i now have run into some trouble.

in the mainframe controller, i use a service called toolbox. it gets injected and i can use it just fine. however when i want to open a second window, which also uses the same service, it doesn't seem to get injected. i keep getting nullpointerexceptions, telling me that toolBox is null.

my spring config is:

```
<bean id="TagListFrame" name="TagListFrame" class="TagListFrame" scope="singleton">
    <property name="toolBox" ref="ToolBoxService"/>
</bean>
<bean id="ToolBoxService" name="ToolBoxService" class="ToolBoxImpl" scope="singleton">
    <property name="tagDao" ref="JDBCTagDao"/>
</bean>
<bean id="JDBCTagDao" name="JDBCTagDao" class="JDBCTagDao" scope="singleton">
    <property name="connection" ref="HSQLDBConnection"/>
</bean>
```

in the TagListFrame controller i defined the variable and a setter for it.

if i call the setter function from the mainframecontroller and use it's reference to the toolbox, it works fine, but i can't seem to get it to work with spring.

I open the new window with the following code:

```
Scene newScene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
Stage newStage = new Stage();
newStage.setTitle("Window Title);
newStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
newStage.setScene(newScene);
newStage.setX(primaryStage.getX() + 100);
newStage.setY(primaryStage.getY() + 100);
newStage.show();
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.service.PictureInfoShowImpl.getAllTags(PictureInfoShowImpl.java:226)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.SinglePictureFrameController.showTags(SinglePictureFrameController.java:243)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.SinglePictureFrameController.setPicture(SinglePictureFrameController.java:196)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.MainFrameController.viewSinglePicture(MainFrameController.java:382)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.ThumbnailFrameController.openSingleImage(ThumbnailFrameController.java:281)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.ThumbnailFrameController.access$600(ThumbnailFrameController.java:37)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.ThumbnailFrameController$2.handle(ThumbnailFrameController.java:251)
at at.ac.tuwien.sepm.ws13.qse01.gui.ThumbnailFrameController$2.handle(ThumbnailFrameController.java:226)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3100)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8600(Scene.java:3038)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3320)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3151)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3106)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:530)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:924)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:89)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

i'd greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: could you post the code where you create the second window. i don't know you do it, but you'll need to have spring g create your beans to autowire fields

Answer (score 0):

From your configuration you can see that you are injecting toolbox service only into `TagListFrame` class object:

```
<bean id="TagListFrame" name="TagListFrame" class="TagListFrame" scope="singleton">
    <property name="toolBox" ref="ToolBoxService"/>
</bean>
```

If you want to inject the same service into other controllers you must specify this injection in your xml the same way you did for TagListFrame. Smth like that

```
<bean id="MyNewController" name="MyNewController" class="MyNewController" scope="singleton">
    <property name="toolBox" ref="ToolBoxService"/>
</bean>
```

P.S. Singleton is the default scope so you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: thanks for the tipp, but that is already what i am doing. this is just part of the spring config.

Comment: and make sure you are not creating service somewhere with keyword new since it has to be Spring managed bean. It would be helpful if you added full stack-trace of the exception